# Bootstrap validating multiple fields but displaying one message

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using a Bootstrap validator plug in order to validate my form however I'm having trouble finding out how to display only one message when validating multiple fields.

[image]

I want to display an error saying "Please enter birthday" if a user does not select a month, day or year however I'm not sure how to group the fields together to print one message.

This is the plug in I am using
https://plugins.jquery.com/bootstrapValidator/

The select options are populated by query

```
    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="date" id="months" name="month">
                            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Month</option>
                        </select>

                        <select class="date" id="days" name="day">
                            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Day</option>
                        </select>

                        <select class="date" id="years" name="year">
                            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Year</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

This is how I am validating my code currently

```
    month  : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message : "Month is required."
                }
            }
        },
        day : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message : "Day is required."
                }
            }
        },
        year : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message : "Year is required."
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which validator plugin are you using? Also, please post your current code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: I made the changes please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @user4332856 Have you found solution for that?